# Why isnt this regex working?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to have a regex pattern for an address similar to the one below but I cant get the test method to return true, what am I doing wrong here?

```
       let reg=/[0-9]{3}\b[a-z]{1}\b\d{2}[a-z]{2}\b[a-z]{2}\b[a-z}{6}\b[a-z]{10}\b[0-9]{5}/;

       let fakeAddress="925 s 10th st tacoma washington 98405";
        reg.test(fakeAddress);
```

Comment: There are no word boundaries between letters and digits. I think you need to replace all `\b` with `\s+`. Also, `[a-z}` should most probably be `[a-z]`. See https://regex101.com/r/QUH5na/1

Comment: You have a curly bracket instead of a bracket at "tacoma" respective test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no [**word boundaries**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) between letters and digits and between digits and letters, you wanted to match whitespace between them. Remember that `\b`, a word boundary, is a *zero-width assertion* that does not consume any chars.  So, you need to replace all `\b` with `\s+` (1 or more whitespace chars). Also, `[a-z}` is a typo. it should be `[a-z]`.

Use

```
/\d{3}\s+[a-z]\s+\d{2}[a-z]{2}\s+[a-z]{2}\s+[a-z]{6}\s+[a-z]{10}\s+[0-9]{5}/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QUH5na/1/)